# Sharing the same .NET type among multiple owned types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm focusing on improving my DDD skills. Yesterday, I encountered an issue when I used the same.net entity type for two attributes in an entity class. I searched online but couldn't find a suitable answer for my problem.

**Context**

*an Entity*

```
    public class SnackMachine: Entity
{
    public virtual Money MoneyInsideMachine { get; protected set; } = Money.None;
    public virtual Money MoneyInTransaction { get; protected set; } = Money.None;

    public SnackMachine()
    {
      
    }

    public virtual void InsertMoney(Money money)
    {
        var coins = new List<Money>()
            {Money.OneCent, Money.TenCent, Money.Quarter, Money.FiveDollar, Money.TwentyDollar, Money.OneDollar};

        if (!coins.Contains(money)) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        MoneyInTransaction += money;
    }

    public virtual void ReturnMoney()
    {
         MoneyInTransaction = Money.None;
    }

    public virtual void BuySnack()
    {
        MoneyInsideMachine += MoneyInTransaction;
        MoneyInTransaction = Money.None;
    }
}
```

*a Value Object*

```
public class Money : ValueObject<Money>
{
    public static readonly Money None = new Money(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Money OneCent = new Money(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Money TenCent = new Money(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Money Quarter = new Money(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Money OneDollar = new Money(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Money FiveDollar = new Money(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    public static readonly Money TwentyDollar = new Money(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    public  int OneCentCount { get; protected set; }
    public  int TenCentCount { get; protected set;}
    public  int QuarterCount { get; protected set;}
    public  int OneDollarCount { get; protected set;}
    public  int FiveDollarCount { get;  protected set;}
    public  int TwentyDollarCount { get; protected set; }

    public decimal Amount =>
        QuarterCount * 0.25m + FiveDollarCount * 5m + OneCentCount * 0.01m + OneDollarCount +
        TenCentCount * 0.1m + TwentyDollarCount * 20m;

    public Money() {}
    public Money(int oneCentCount, int tenCentCount, int quarterCount, int oneDollarCount, int fiveDollarCount,
        int twentyDollarCount) : this()
    {
        ....
    }

    public static Money operator +(Money money1, Money money2)
    {
        .....
    }
    public static Money operator -(Money money1, Money money2)
    {
        .....
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        ....
    }

    protected override bool EqualsCore(Money other)
    {
        ....
    }

    protected override int GetHashCodeCore()
    {
       .....
    }
```

*DbContext*

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SnackMachine?> SnackMachines { get; set; }
    
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) {}
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new SnackMachineEntityTypeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<SnackMachine>());
    }
}
```

*Entity Configuration*

```
public class SnackMachineEntityTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<SnackMachine>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SnackMachine> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.MoneyInsideMachine);
        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.MoneyInTransaction);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

```
public SnackMachine? NewSnackMachine()
    {
        var sm = new SnackMachine();
        DbContext.SnackMachines.Add(sm);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return sm;
    }
```

**Output**

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.2 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite:6.0.2' with options: MigrationsAssembly=DDD.Persistence
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10001]
      The same entity is being tracked as different entity types 'SnackMachine.MoneyInsideMachine#Money' and 'SnackMachine.MoneyInTransaction#Money' with defining navigations. If a property value changes, it will result in two store
 changes, which might not be the desired outcome.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10001]
      The same entity is being tracked as different entity types 'SnackMachine.MoneyInsideMachine#Money' and 'SnackMachine.MoneyInTransaction#Money' with defining navigations. If a property value changes, it will result in two store
 changes, which might not be the desired outcome.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'SnackMachine.MoneyInsideMachine#Money' because its primary key property 'SnackMachineId' is null.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknown
Key)
```

**Migration**

```
// <auto-generated />
using DDD.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

#nullable disable

namespace DDD.Persistence.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "6.0.2");

            modelBuilder.Entity("DDD.Domain.SnackMachine", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<string>("Id")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("SnackMachines");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("DDD.Domain.SnackMachine", b =>
                {
                    b.OwnsOne("DDD.Domain.Money", "MoneyInTransaction", b1 =>
                        {
                            b1.Property<string>("SnackMachineId")
                                .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                            b1.Property<int>("FiveDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("OneCentCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("OneDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("QuarterCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("TenCentCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("TwentyDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.HasKey("SnackMachineId");

                            b1.ToTable("SnackMachines");

                            b1.WithOwner()
                                .HasForeignKey("SnackMachineId");
                        });

                    b.OwnsOne("DDD.Domain.Money", "MoneyInsideMachine", b1 =>
                        {
                            b1.Property<string>("SnackMachineId")
                                .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                            b1.Property<int>("FiveDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("OneCentCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("OneDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("QuarterCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("TenCentCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.Property<int>("TwentyDollarCount")
                                .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                            b1.HasKey("SnackMachineId");

                            b1.ToTable("SnackMachines");

                            b1.WithOwner()
                                .HasForeignKey("SnackMachineId");
                        });

                    b.Navigation("MoneyInTransaction")
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("MoneyInsideMachine")
                        .IsRequired();
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SnackMachineId is null` is the error, which is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Hello Charles; I didn't post it  because SnackMachineId has been generated with the migration. I have updated my post

Comment: Your code has no sense. Money is a value type, so it has no Id. EF will use it's value to retrieve and update. The snackMachineId can discriminate rows from different machines, but you have two instances with the same value and EF does not know which row is for inTransaction, and which one is for insideMachine.

Comment: If you had a non zero initial value, it would work at first, but then would break whenever both states of a given machine where identical. You should reconsider your database model.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for those insights Arwyn :) It was very helpful.